# Can't sum a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, list, sum

I just want to print the length and sum of array values, that I input into the list.

Here is my code:

```
arr = list()
for x in range(1,6):
    print("Enter num ", x ," :")
    name = input()
    arr.append(name)
print ("ARRAY: ",arr)
l = len(arr)
s = sum(arr)
print (int(l,s))
```

And the output is:

```
ARRAY:  ['4', '2', '3', '4', '6']                                                                                                                                                  
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                                                 
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>                                                                                                                                              
    s = sum(arr)                                                                                                                                                                   
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: convert your string array to int array and then sum it

Comment: Thank you Albin, I am new to python programming. Could you help me how to do the conversion from string array to int array in my script ?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you *should* be able to sum a list of strings (with a suitable initial value), except `sum` is hard-coded to prevent it. `sum(['4', '2'], '')` should return `'42'`, just like `sum([[4], [2]], [])` can return `[4,2]`. It's not an arbitrary decision--its recommendation of `''.join(x)` is much more efficient than `sum(x, '')` would be--but still, it's annoying to have a perfectly logical operation banned purely for performance reasons. (Worse, there's no reason I can think of that `sum` couldn't simply do `''.join(x)` itself  in the event it detects an attempt to sum strings.)

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two issues.

- [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string, so you need to cast it to a integer before, you can  `sum` the values.
- This `print (int(l,s))` doesn't really make any sense. If you look at the documentation of [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int), you can see that you are passing `s` as the base for the function, but it will fail, since the base can only be specified if the first agument is a string.

Here's a fixed version. I also used a [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-f-string) to place `x` in the input prompt:

```
arr = list()
for x in range(1, 6):
    name = int(input(f"Enter num {x}: "))
    arr.append(name)
print("ARRAY: ", arr)
l = len(arr)
s = sum(arr)
print(l, s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
arr = list()
for x in range(1,6):
    print("Enter num ", x ," :")
    name = int(input())
    arr.append(name)
print ("ARRAY: ",arr)
l = len(arr)
s = sum(arr)
print (l,s)
```

Comment: Yes it works, but I only remove int from the last line:

print (int(l,s))

print (l,s)